# How to add a Web Part Zone to a SharePoint wiki page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a team site. I understand that the default home page of a team site is a wiki page. I want to add a web part zone to this page. How can I do that? By default it already has Web Part Zone -.

You can use SharePoint designer to add a web part to this zone and it works fine. But you are not able to add a web part to this zone using SharePoint web UI? Ususally when you have a web part zone in a page, using SharePoint web UI, it allows to you add/remove a web part. But it is not the case with the web part zone on the default home page of a team site.

Also is there any way I can add a web part zone to this page? I do know that you can easily add web parts into wiki page content. But I want to add a new web part zone where users can add/remove web parts.

Thanks, Hitesh

Comment: a similar purpose is asked [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/side-by-side-web-parts-on-a-wiki-page-possible). Maybe it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the web part **zone** in SharePoint Designer?

Also, just in case you didn't know, you can turn off the wiki default page by deactivating the feature at the site level.

Answer (score 0):

Wiki pages cannot have web part zones [doc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f82be255-ae1f-42bd-9bac-318b5c6759ff/how-to-add-a-web-part-zone-to-a-wiki-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Answer (score -2):

You can add a web part to this using the web UI as well just open the page in edit mode click on insert ribbon menu you would get option to add a webpart

Comment: I understand that I can easily add a web part to a wiki page. My question is how, if possible, to add a "Web Part Zone" to a wiki page?

Comment: You are trying to add a new page to wiki library. wiki library pages are not for adding webpart zone create a web part page by clicking on site actions create new page link if you see it their or on more option which will lead you to a link to create new page their select a option to add a webpart page and then keep on adding as many webpart or webpart zone you need

Comment: Yes I do know about web part pages and the ability of adding as many web part or webpart zone as I want. All i wanted to know whether a webpart zone can be added to a wiki page or not. Or is it something like that the wiki pages are designed not to have webpart zones? Never mind, thanks for your time.